# Pandas IF statement referencing other column value

Tags: python, pandas

I can't for the life of me find an example of this operation in pandas.... I am trying to write an IF statement saying IF my Check column is true then pull the value from my Proficiency_Value column, and if it's False, then default to 1000.

```
report_skills['Check'] = report_skills.apply(lambda x: x.Skill_Specialization in x.Specialization, axis=1)
report_skills = report_skills.loc[report_skills['Check'] == True, 'Proficiency_Value'] = 1000
```

Any ideas why this is not working? I'm sure this is an easy fix

Comment: `np.where(report_skills['Check'] == True,report_skills['Proficiency_Value'],1000)`?

Comment: for future, you can reference this link ... https://datatofish.com/if-condition-in-pandas-dataframe/

Answer (score 1):

Let`s create a small example DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Check':[True,False, False ,True], 
                   'Proficiency_Value':range(4)
                  })

>>> df
   Check  Proficiency_Value
0   True                  0
1  False                  1
2  False                  2
3   True                  3
```

If you use now the `np.where()` functione, you can get the result you are asking for.

```
df['Proficiency_Value'] = np.where(df['Check']==True, df['Proficiency_Value'], 1000)

>>> df
   Check  Proficiency_Value
0   True                  0
1  False               1000
2  False               1000
3   True                  3
```